# Spring Security Rest web application and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are trying to develop a web application which will have only Rest Controller. 
We are trying to use Spring Security and Angular JS as web client.

I have below queries:-

1. Should i have only have Basic Authentication.
2. I want user to be authenticated using Login page since for user of
   my web application i cant ask them to use basic authentication? How
   can i overcome this
3. Should i disable session in spring ?
4. For web application users for every subsequent request do they
   have to pass credentials in request    headers?

Comment: What about token based authentication?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Should i have only have Basic Authentication.

You must use standard authentication method with application username and password.

> 2. I want user to be authenticated using Login page since for user of my web application i cant ask them to use basic authentication? How can i overcome this

Yes you can accept user credentials from login page and authenticate at server side using REST services.

> 3. Should i disable session in spring ?

Each HTTP RESTful request is a stateless request. Session are irrelevant in RESTful. You need to pass username/password and token with each request to identify particular user.

> 4. For web application users for every subsequent request do they have to pass credentials in request headers?

Not needed. You can accept username/password only in first request, authenticate and provide unique token to client. This token then would be sent to server for each subsequent request to identify user on server. You can set expiration time for the token.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example project here: https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity

I've used this and it's simple to set up, and easy to use.